# 'str' object is not callable in Django url pattern

Tags: django, url

In my urls.py file, I have

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       (r'^$',home_page),
                       #(r'^'+main_cagetory_url_string+'$','home_page'),
                       (r'^(?:cam_sanh|buoi_da_xanh|cam_da_xanh)$','home_page'),
                       (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),)
```

I want to use that pattern to access cam_sanh, buoi_da_xanh, cam_da_xanh page.
But I receive error:

```
'str' object is not callable
```

How can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this line specifically, `(r'^(?:cam_sanh|buoi_da_xanh|cam_da_xanh)$','home_page'),`, the second tuple element should be a callback function, not a string.

This should fix it:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$',home_page),
    (r'^(?:cam_sanh|buoi_da_xanh|cam_da_xanh)$',home_page),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Django will attempt to lookup the view using the string you provide, however, you need to specify the full view path, aka, 'my_project.view_name'

Alternatively, you can do as Filip suggested and give it the view name as the callback but then you need to import the view into your urls.py file.